# Unable to persiste data with Spring Data Redis

Tags: java, spring, redis

I am experimenting with Spring Data Redis. I have written a Java class that allows me to connect to Redis server but doesn't persist data in the server. Would someone have an idea as to what might be wrong? Following are some details-

My spring config looks like-

```
<bean id="jedisConnFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory" p:use-pool="true"  p:host-name="127.0.0.1" p:port="6379"/>

<!-- redis template definition -->
<bean id="redisTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate"
    p:connection-factory-ref="jedisConnFactory"/>
```

My Java code looks like this-

```
public class CacheClient {

   @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, String> template;
    public void setValue(String key, String value){
      template.boundValueOps(key).set(value);
    }
}
```

Once I have invoked template.setValue(key,value), I do a "get key" on redis-cli but I don't see any value set for the key.

Could someone help with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

@user2862924 You are right in your comment, it serializes key and value. It uses JdkSerializationRedisSerializer() which converts string `"a"`  to `\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x01a`

`redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());` is what you want.

Setting this value from configuration file is cleaner.

```
<bean id="stringRedisSerializer" class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer"/>

    <bean id="jedisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
          p:hostName="127.0.0.1" p:port="6379"/>

    <bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate"
          p:connectionFactory-ref="jedisConnectionFactory" p:keySerializer-ref="stringRedisSerializer" p:valueSerializer-ref="stringRedisSerializer"/>
```

Before changing serialization method, delete all previously serialized key-values from store or you will get error.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `opsForValue()`

```
public void setValue(String key, String value){
      template.opsForValue().set(key, value);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Raffian. I figured out that with either of boundValueOps or opsForValue, I can't retrieve the value from redis-cli though I can retrieve it through the respective get methods (of  BoundValueOperations or Operations). I think Spring serializes both, the key and value, by default and when we fetch, we need to fetch using the same serialized key (though I haven't verified this part).